# Directive's scope not initialized prior to loading the directive template leading to not loading of Google Map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive, angularjs-google-maps

I am working with the [Google-maps-angular](http://angular-google-maps.org/) directive in my app and I am trying to wrap that directive within my own directive. It works fine if I define the map object in the controller. But when I define the map object inside the link function, it doesn't seem to be getting the map object.

I tried defining the map object inside the directive's controller, but that didn't load the map either. The scope doesn't seem to be initialized prior to loading the html which explains why the map won't load, but I haven't been able to figure out why this is the case. Is there any other way I can define the map object inside the directive instead of an outside controller?

Also when looking inside the google-map's scope (using angular.element("google-map >").scope() ), it shows center to be defined so I am unsure why the map isn't loaded.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[
        'google-maps',
    ])

app.directive('myDir', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: '<google-map center="map.center" zoom="13" draggable="true" pan= "1" control="map.control"></google-map>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.map = {
                center: {
                    latitude: 40.35,
                    longitude: -74.6702
                },
                control:{}
            }
        },
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that you are not asking about [ngMap](http://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps), but I found this way is a lot easier than http://angular-google-maps.org/

Here is the plunker, http://plnkr.co/edit/ZwUARi7OC2vUnJS6UdBD?p=preview

and this is your directive

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMap']);

app.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: '<map center="{{mapOptions.center}}" zoom="13" draggable="true" pan="1"></map>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    },
  };
});
```

It shouldn't be that hard. btw, I am the creator of [ngMap](http://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps)

Comment: Oh, pub :-) I wrote two example of controller with maps as custom directive, and in one case, the controller was initialized before the directive has been compiled. To be able to handle this case, I wrote a service how was charged to resolve a promise, only when the map is fully loaded. Create this directive is a good think, but you must create your own object, with new google.maps.Map. A little details; as precised in the gmap doc, it only works on a div with a fixed heigt.